# Xcode 4.3 Master-Detail Application for iPad: navigation bar out of synch on fullscreen video rotation

Tags: ios5, xcode4, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller, master-detail

Really weird situation. My app plays a fullscreen video. If I rotate the screen orientation while the video is playing, when it exits fullscreen and the master navigation and / or detail navigation bars return, they are pushed up from their proper position.

[image]

Really weird is that, if I rotate the screen quickly while the status bar shows the video still loading or if I tap the screen to make it appear before rotation, the navigation bars are positioned correctly when the video finishes.

I have read numerous posts on this problem and solved it with my iPhone app by doing the following when the video exits full screen:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

but the workaround doesn't work with the iPad version I am creating with Xcode 4.3.  If I play the video and don't rotate, when the video finishes, I do see the navigation bar disappear and appear caused by the above code. But on rotation it doesn't work. I also tried placing that code in the

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
```

method but that doesn't work either.

Every where I have read about this people say it's a bug but I just feel like it must be something I am missing in my code.

If anyone can help with this, I will greatly appreciate it.